# Laravel 8 - Model factory class not found when creating a dummy data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently following the laravel from scratch series from laracasts and I got stuck on this problem since the laravel version on that series is laravel 6. I already searched for an answer here and found a similar thread but my case is different, since i installed a fresh laravel 8 version.

I'm creating a dummy data using the factory model class using this command on tinker:

```
Article::factory()->count(1)->make();
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Article' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1
```

Here's my model Article.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Here's my factory ArticleFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Article;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class ArticleFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Article::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => User::factory(),
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'excerpt' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'body' => $this->faker->paragraph
        ];
    }
}
```

I tried creating a dummy data using the default model and factory for User and it's perfectly working. I was using the same code on tinker:

```
>>> User::factory()->count(1)->make();
[!] Aliasing 'User' to 'App\Models\User' for this Tinker session.
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3289
     all: [
       App\Models\User {#3294
         name: "Lane Maggio I",
         email: "tromp.deion@example.com",
         email_verified_at: "2020-10-19 15:08:24",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` after creating the model/factory? Sometimes class definitions are missing from `tinker` (and other console commands) until that command is run.

Comment: Yes about that, i changed the make() to create() so its saved on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following snippet on the top of your file;

```
use App\Models\Article;
```

Comment: Wow it worked thanks a lot, i added it on the Article.php itself.